# Loading files into memory stream buffer then modify and save it back onto harddrive

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am working on vb.net win form. My task is display the file names from a folder onto gridview control. when user clicks process button in my UI, all the file names present in gridview, the corresponding file has to be loaded onto memory stream buffer one after another and append the titles to the content of the file and save it in hard drive with _ed as a suffix to the file name.

I am very basic programmer. I have done the following attempt and succeeded in displaying filenames onto gridview. But no idea of later part. Any suggestions please?

'Displaying files from a folder onto a gridview

```
Dim inqueuePath As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\INQUEUE"     
Dim fileInfo() As String     Dim rowint As Integer = 0
Dim name As String     Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(inqueuePath)
fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inqueuePath)
  With Gridview1         
       .Columns.Add("Column 0", "FileName")         
       .AutoResizeColumns()     
  End With
For Each name In fileInfo         
    Gridview1.Rows.Add()         
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name)         
    Gridview1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename         
    rowint = rowint + 1     
Next
```

Thank you very much for spending your valuable time to read this post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StreamWriter` to easily write to a file. No need to first put the file contents into a `MemoryStream`. But don't forget to `Seek` to the end of the file after opening it, otherwise you will overwrite the contents at the beginning of the file.

Something like this:

```
File.Copy(filename, newFilename)

Using writer = New StreamWriter(newFilename)
    writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.[End])
    writer.Write(filename)
End Using
```

Try fixing any errors in my sample code yourself... It helps you understand the code.